# Google Cloud Functions (Alpha), Spring cloud for gradle?

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-cloud-functions, spring-cloud

Currently, I am following spring cloud for google cloud function in [this sample](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-function/reference/html/gcp.html#_google_cloud_functions_alpha). But the sample just implement configuration for maven. How do I implement it in Gradle?

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class CloudFunctionMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CloudFunctionMain.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public Function<String, String> uppercase() {
        return value -> value.toUpperCase();
    }
}
```

Comment: For the local compilation, it should work in the same way (you can run it locally). However, during my latest tests, the Gradle plugin wasn't ready for the deployment of the Cloud Functions. I don't know the status now.

Comment: How can I convert maven to gradle to run locally?

Comment: Step 1: You must have gradle installed on your machine. ...
Step 2: Run gradle init in the directory containing the (master) pom. ...
Step 3: Run gradlew build in the directory containing build.

Comment: I hope this Github link answers your question: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/spring-cloud-gcp/issues/445